# Can Chrome or Firefox open a network port and serve connections using javascript?

Tags: javascript, security, browser, webrtc, port

For a mostly offline browser game I'm researching the possibility to run a WebRTC signalling server from a browser.

I can imagine that security-wise it's a big no-no to open a port and serve connections from a browser (or service worker), but I cannot* find any information on this.

**Q. Can Chrome, Firefox (or perhaps any other major browser) open a network port and serve connections using javascript? Or is this fundamentally disallowed by browser design?**

**) For sake of completeness, I did find one option (maybe), but it's overly complex, and therefore isn't very appealing. There is a javascript package called filerjs, which allows for a posix-like filesytem in the browser, I think using indexedb, that would allow for a nodejs installation in the browser. I did not further investigate it, so no idea if it actually works, and if a connection could be served this way.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can run a signaling server in the browser. But you say "mostly offline", does that mean that the peers are connected to the internet, but playing from the same LAN? Or are they completely offline? Here are a few ideas:

#### Signaling server on the web

Even if the signaling server is running on the web, chances are that WebRTC will connect directly through the LAN (to be tested, and it may depend on how the browser selects the ICE candidates).

#### Manual signaling

Now, the signaling server is only there to exchange SDP messages. So you could theoretically copy-paste the offer and answer (or copy it manually, or scan it with a QR code). It may not be practical, but for instance you could try hardcoding the SDP offer/answer. The two players would need to exchange information somehow, though:

1. The ICE candidates (those are IPs) that you would need to create the SDP message
2. The SDP type (one has to be the offer, the other has to be the answer)

I never tried it, but maybe your UI could tell the player "Please share the following IPs to the other player, and enter their IPs below. Also select if you are the offerer or the answerer". But you see that it seems a bit convoluted...

#### Signaling server in the LAN

If the peers are completely offline and the manual signaling is too convoluted, my next idea would be to run the signaling server in the LAN, and have the peers connect to it. You could even make it such that your game first tries to contact your signaling server on the Internet, and if it fails (because it is offline), it could fallback and try to contact the one in the LAN (maybe it would need to ask the user for the IP of the signaling server, then).

Comment: Mostly offline: Players are disconnected and use WiFi direct to setup a LAN, however, at some point in the past they have had an internet connection to install and set things up. So for all intents and purposes, they are completely offline. --- I considered using QR codes, but I think that requires two QR codes to be scanned to complete the offer/accept handshake, which is a bit cumbersome. --- Is hardcoding the offer/accept handshake an option? It seems it contains network information that is not knowable up-front right?

Comment: Displaying the IP to copy might not be too bad, but I think the smoothes experience is your last suggestion. This thing is currently a web-app (PWA), it shouldn't be too hard to create an Android and iOS app version from that. In an app you have access to all kinds of mDNS and signalling goodness that should automagically connect all players. In this scenario at least one player must use the app-version.

Comment: If that's for smartphones, I would probably go for your latest suggestion where one player has to run the signaling server. That would provide the best UX IMO.